# Position UIPageController over UITabBar and iAd

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am trying to position the UIPageController on top of my UITabBar and iAd.

So if the iAd disappears or have not been opened yet then the UIPageController should be on top of UITabBar. When my iAd animates and comes forth it should just be moved over iAd. NO idea how to implement this, Tried using constraints etc but did not go so well. Any other way that is easier?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

If you look closely on the UITabBar you can se a dot. Thats the position of my UIPageController

Comment: Set a constraint so that the top of the iAd is the bottom of the page controller. Set a constraint so that the bottom of the iAd is the top of the tab bar. Create an IBoutlet reference to this second constraint. When the iAd should be hidden set the constant to - the height of the tab bar. When it should be visible set it to 0.  Animate these changes.

Comment: Any code snippets that would be great help. Been trying with no progress. @Paulw11